# What is a more politically correct way to call something a "Red-Headed Step-Child"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, popular-refrains, political-correctness

I can't use the phrase "second-class citizen" either.

This is for a professional blog post, so I'd rather stay away from "red-headed step-child".  I can't use "second-class citizen" because I'm talking about a topic with very few similar posts and one related post uses that same term.  If I really need to use "second-class citizen" then I'll probably just reference the other post.

EDIT: For those of you who are not familiar with the term, it is meant to be like a child who is cast away and treated differently than the rest of the family.  If you watch Game of Thrones, Jon Snow is the red-headed step-child of the Stark family.

I think the term "black sheep" might be similar, but "black sheep" usually means that the person did something to harm his own standing.

EDIT2: I'd rather not get into the details of the blog post because it's pretty niche.  Let's just use the following example:

"When you talk about smartphone OS development, iOS and Android are the over-achieving college kids, Windows Phone is the unemployed pot-smoking brother, and Blackberry OS is the red-headed step-child."

I won't actually be mentioning the other competing products, but I just wanted to illustrate what the term would be calling out.

Comment: I've never heard that before. What does red headed step child mean and where does it come from?

Comment: If you're talking about a particular person then use their name. If you want to point out particular things about that person or class of people, be particular, with usual sensitivity.

Comment: I've never heard this either, though I guess it means someone who is doubly disadvantaged by being a step-child and red-haired, if you follow the prejudice against red-haired people. How about 'persona non grata'

Comment: ["A red-haired child born to a family of different colouring immediately caused questions to be asked about the morality of its mother and *stepchild* here may indeed have been a euphemism for *bastard*."](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-red2.htm)

Comment: I don't think the term "red-headed" is meant to be derogatory towards red-haired people, it's just that a red haired person would stick out as different (at least genetically) in most family photos.

Comment: ginger offspring? :p

Comment: Mulling this over in my own head, I think a politically correct equivalent might be "Rodney Dangerfield" (as in "he never gets any respect").

Comment: @Chris This blog post isn't about a person.  It's about an aspect of software development, so no feelings are going to get hurt.  I'm really trying to be sensitive to people who may have been adopted or raised by a parent other than their own.

Comment: @JackAce: Can you elaborate a bit more what you're writing about? You seem to be skirting around the subject so it's hard for an IT professional (like myself) to understand what you're trying to state about software development.

Comment: It might be easier to answer this question if you explain _what_ you are referring to, when you would use the term red-headed stepchild (or equivalent idiom).

Comment: @Chris & J.R. -- Example posted in the original post.

Comment: I would say that Windows Phone is for the unemployed undying believer in outdated technology and Blackberry is for those wishing it was still 1990s when solitare rocked CEOs' worlds. Anyhow, you get the idea, the phrases describing each don't need to follow exact same format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of these give general feelings which may (or may not) suggest  a satisfactory term.
 Some may fit as-is. One can hope :-).

- persona non grata.
- throwback
- standout
- developmental backwater  (good for software)
- odd man out
- knife at a gun fight (getting desperate)
- black sheep of the family
- " ... C and all its bastard children" - Jerry Pournelle in full flight.
- evolutionary throwback.
- As useful as xxx on a yyy
- Like a xxx in yyy (eg snowball / hell, ...)

Answer (score 9):

Consider:

- [Pariah](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pariah)

  - *An outcast.*
  - *A demographic group, species, or community that is generally despised.*
  - *Someone in exile.*
  - *A person who is rejected (from society or home).*
- [Outcast](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/outcast): *One that has been excluded from a society or system, a pariah.*
- [Condemned](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/condemned): *Having received a curse to be doomed to suffer eternally.*
- [Also-ran](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/also-ran): *A person or animal who competed in a race but did not win.*
- [Has-been](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/has-been): *A person, especially one formerly popular or influential, who continues in their field after their popularity or effectiveness has peaked and is now in decline.*
- [Third wheel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/third_wheel)

  - *A person or thing that serves no useful purpose.*
  - *An unwanted third party accompanying two people on a date.*
- [Spare wheel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spare_wheel): *An extra wheel held in reserve in most cars, to be used in an emergency.*
- [Fifth wheel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fifth_wheel): *Anything superfluous or unnecessary.*

Answer (score 7):

For a reasonably contemporary literary reference, how about "the orphan nephew living in the cupboard under the stairs"?

Comment: Much like Cinderella, then?

Comment: @user867 Ah. Now we're talking about Mythic Archetypes; but that would be Literary Criticism (or possibly Structural Anthropology), and therefore Off Topic. :)

Answer (score 3):

*The Cinderella*, particularly if the relative lack of respect is unwarranted. (And who by coincidence, is also a step child).

Comment: This is good, but it connotes that the entity will eventually triumph, like a "Cinderella Story".

Comment: @JackAce I don't think it so much connotes that, as that they might deserve to, as per what I say about "particularly if the relative lack of respect is unwarranted".

Answer (score 2):

Another expression that could be used is *"Belonging to the 'island of misfit toys'."*